# Loop the select query result set in MYSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How to loop the resultset of query and in loop the resultset get the column value and fire insert query on database.

Below is My SP:

```
Input parameter listvalues and value is 1,2,3,4,5

SET @t1 = CONCAT("SELECT ID FROM interest WHERE ID IN(",listvalues,")");
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @t1;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Then how to loop the stmt1 to get all ID values to insert in another table.

**My SP:**

```
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO `registration`(`FirstName`,`LastName`,`EMail`,`PhoneNumber`,`Gender`,`State`,`City`,`ImagePath`,`IsDeleted`,`CreatedDate`,`ModifiedDate`)
VALUES(FirstName,LastName,EMail,PhoneNumber,Gender,State,City,ImagePath,0,NOW(),NOW());

SET @RegID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

SET @t1 = CONCAT("INSERT INTO `userinterest` (`InterestId` , `UserId`) VALUES((SELECT ID FROM interest WHERE ID IN(",InterestList,")),",@RegID,")");
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

END
```

But it give error **Subquery returns more than 1 row**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've write stored procedure as:

```
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO `registration`(`FirstName`,`LastName`,`EMail`,`PhoneNumber`,`Gender`,`State`,`City`,`ImagePath`,`IsDeleted`,`CreatedDate`,`ModifiedDate`)
VALUES(FirstName,LastName,EMail,PhoneNumber,Gender,State,City,ImagePath,0,NOW(),NOW());

SET @RegID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

SET @t1 = CONCAT("INSERT INTO `userinterest` (`InterestId` , `UserId`) SELECT ID AS InterestId, ",@RegID," AS UserId FROM interest WHERE ID IN(",InterestList,")");
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the `INSERT` in the query:

```
SET @t1 = CONCAT("INSERT INTO otherTable (interest_id)
                  SELECT ID FROM interest WHERE ID IN(",listvalues,")");
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. finally I've write the SP using your answer. thanks once again.